# Teradata - Remove numbers and certain punctuation, leave alpha and other punctuation

Tags: regex, teradata

I need to cleanup a name field in Teradata.  Some entries are good:

- Belcher, Bob X.
- Belcher, Linda A.
- Pesto, Jimmy Z.

Others also have numbers, semicolon and pound/hash:

- 372;#Fishoder, Calvin Z.
- 5907;#Fishoder, Felix W.
- 43;#Francisco, Teddy A.

The 2nd set of examples is what I need to cleanup, but leave the comma between last and first name, and period after middle initial.

I'm assuming REGEX_REPLACE is what I need, but can't find examples of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can use this simple regex: [A-Z].* and set the multiline option, if there's more than one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexp_replace is your friend here.  You can replace multiple characters by putting them inside square brackets.  So if you want to replace `#` or `;` or any numeric character:

```
select
regexp_replace('AB,;#123','[;#0-9]','',1,0,'i')
```

In that lovely made up example, you'll get back `AB,`. We've removed the semi colon and the numbers.

Running it with one of your examples:

```
select
regexp_replace('372;#Fishoder, Calvin Z.','[;#0-9]','',1,0,'i')
```

Gives us back
`Fishoder, Calvin Z.`

Answer (score 1):

Here, we might want to start with a left boundary `[A-Z]`, then collect the last name, followed by comma, and rest of our string, with an expression similar to:

```
(([A-Z].+)?,)\s*(.+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Irxjrf/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Capturing Groups

```js
const regex = /(([A-Z].+)?,)\s*(.+)/gm;
const str = `372;#Fishoder, Calvin Z.
5907;#Fishoder, Felix W.
43;#Francisco, Teddy A.
Belcher, Bob X.
Belcher, Linda A.
Pesto, Jimmy Z.`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```